# nhibernate: can't determine data type of aggregate

Tags: nhibernate

Any suggestion how to fix this error? (I'd rather not create an sql view to skirt the issue with the sum aggregate)

"Can't extract the type of one parameter of a HQL function: expression->{TreatmentTime}; check aliases. [select new TherapyMinutesDisciplineByDayDTO( sum(TreatmentTime), 2.0, 3.0, t.TreatmentDate, p.LastName, d.Description ) from TherapyMinutesModule.TherapySession t join t._Patient p join t._Discipline d group by t.TreatmentDate, p.LastName, d.Description]"

Here's the hql:

```
                    c.HSQL = "select"
                     + " new TherapyMinutesDisciplineByDayDTO( sum(TreatmentTime), 2.0, 3.0, t.TreatmentDate, p.LastName, d.Description )"
                     + " from TherapySession t"
                     + " join t._Patient p"
                     + " join t._Discipline d"
                     + " group by t.TreatmentDate, p.LastName, d.Description"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t.TreatmentTime?

---

Edit:

From comments below since my answer wasn't clear at all (sorry)

replace:

```
sum(TreatmentTime)
```

with

```
sum(t.TreatmentTime)
```

Comment: yah, but isn't TreatmentTime a member of TherapySession?

Comment: Imagine the SQL you would write ... select t.TreatmentDate, sum(t.TreatmentTime) from TherapySession t group by t.TreatmentDate ... right? (ignoring the patient / discipline stuff atm).

Comment: That's the correct sql. I think it's trying to do it but can't figure out the data type of the sum() aggregate function. If I do it without the sum it works just fine. I could move the sum to a view but I'd prefer to avoid that hack if possible. The database already has too much cruft in it.

Comment: You have sum(TreatmentTime) instead of sum(t.TreatmentTime) is what I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry for the cryptic original answer.  I wasn't 100% sure that was right, so I didn't want to proclaim too strongly.  I updated the answer for anyone else who comes here.